# Problem emulating phone camera with a normal USB webcam

Tags: xamarin.forms, camera, webcam

I'm developing a simple Xamarin Form using VS2019 and Oreo as simulated android.
I would like to use my USB Logitech Webcam 200 in order to simulate phone camera. 
This basically to avoid the deploymnet of the app in the phone with USB and save time.

I've configured the ADM adding hw.camera property and enabling it. Than i've tried to set hw.back.camera to webcam0 and hw.front.camera to none, but when i open camera in the emulated device it gives an error and camera app crash, also my app doesn't work.

I've tried to check the log and mainly i've found: E/CamDev@3.2-impl(1393): open: cannot open camera 0!
My webcam is good and drivers are installed on my win10 (i use it regularly with Skype and other apps).

I also tried with VS2017 in my PC and also tried in another PC with VS2019.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey Kyle, welcome to StackOverflow. It seems this question is less about programming code and more about software being used. You may be more likely to get a good answer over on https://superuser.com/. Good luck finding a solution :)

Comment: Ok i'll give it a try, thank you.